# LookUpRows on rowset created with function BuildRowSetFromString

Tags: exacttarget, ampscript

Is it possible to apply a function like LookUpRows or Lookup to an array created with BuildRowSetFromString?

I have this:

```
SET @rowSet = BuildRowSetFromString(@ItemsString2, '|')
```

I'd like to know if there's a function on which I can do:

```
SET @var = LookupRows(@rowSet, ITEM_ID, ... )
```

I am trying already using a FOR loop. I want to know if there's a function that can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. I wish.

Best bet would be to use arrays in [Server-Side JavaScript](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/server_side_javascript/) or possibly [GTL](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/guide_template_language/).

If you want to over-engineer it, you can use XML and XPATH to do some array functions in AMPScript.  I've written up a use-case with examples [here](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ca-xml/) on my personal blog.

Also, there is a lot more SFMC dicussion going on over in [http://salesforce.stackexchange.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud).